# What is Doha Airport like for a single 17-year-old female?

Tags: airports, solo-travel, female-travellers, doha

I am a 17-year-old girl, flying from the UK to Doha by myself to then fly from Doha to Perth also on my own. I have a layover of 1 hour and 20 minutes. How easy is Doha airport to navigate to get to a connecting flight? Is it safe? Is there anything I should know?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally speaking, airports are decently safe and clean places to be once you are past security. Security screening, security presence and the cost of a ticket tends to depress undesirable behavior in these areas. That doesn't mean nothing bad can happen to you, just that it is nothing that I would be inherently worried about.

Comment: Okay thank you, what exactly do you mean by ‘the cost of a ticket tends to depress undesirable behaviour in these areas’ ?

Comment: Generally you can't get into the gate areas unless you have a ticket to fly. So the price of a ticket is a natural barrier to keep most people (good or bad) out. In other words, people can't just walk in off the street to reach the secured areas.

Comment: @IzzyBulcraig Past security, there is nobody in the airport "just hanging around" - they all have a reason to be there, and nobody is going to pay the price of a ticket in order to be able to pick a few pockets.  (That doesn't mean you shouldn't be careful - just that it's probably safer than, eg, the sleazier parts of Sydney.)

Comment: Ohhh right okay I understand what you both mean, thank you. Yes I know that no one can get through security just randomly haha! I just know that there rules with women are different so I just wanted to be on the safe side of it was okay to travel on my own through there but these responses have all eased my anxiousness so thank you both!

Comment: Airport websites are a mine of information for travellers, including facilities, maps, etc.  The site for Hamad International is here: https://dohahamadairport.com/

Answer (score 2):

Doha Airport is a very safe and clean place. You will see signs everywhere for direction and it is a delightful place to be. I have travelled through their Airport many times and I like it a lot.
Also your layover time should be enough, i have never waited more than 15 minutes for the security check.

Just to add a source, they ranked 5th best Airport on SKYTRAX which you can see on there own [website](https://dohahamadairport.com/media/hamad-international-airport-ranked-5th-best-airport-world-skytrax-world-airport-awards-2018).

Comment: Thank you so much! That has put me at ease. I am Australian but have never done this flight from the UK ( I live there) to aus on my own so I’m nervous. I’m flying with British Airways, do I need to wait in line for any passport check things? Is there people around to help and ask questions with? Do I need to keep my shoulders and knees covered or would I be okay haha? Thank you again !!

Comment: As planes can be cold and you will be sitting on an airplane seat for many hours, you might want to travel with (thin) long trousers and a blouse that covers your shoulders and arms. If it is hot in the airport building you can take it off when you see others showing their shoulders.

Comment: After leaving your plane to Doha you will go through a security check and then go to your Gate where your passport and boarding pass will be checked to get into the boarding area of your next plane. Then you will sit there for some minutes before you can enter the plane. In my experience all the Airports in really hot regions, like Doha, tend to cool down their airports a lot, so you will probably be cold with too much skin showing. I would recommend covering your shoulders and knees for religious reasons although Qatar isn't really strict on this, i won't hurt to do so.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to be on the conservative side when visiting another country, but there are plenty of women with uncovered knees and shoulders inside the airport in Qatar. (It'd be different if you're going outside the airport.)